# $\mathcal{L}\{y(t)\}=(1/s)\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$

Tags: laplace-transform

> If $y(t)=\int_{0}^t f(t)dt$ & the Laplace transform of $f(t)$ is
>   $\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}=\int_{0}^\infty e^{-st}f(t)dt$,then prove that
>   $\mathcal{L}\{y(t)\}=(1/s)\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$.

My attempt:Since, $\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}=\int_{0}^\infty e^{-st}f(t)dt$,then $\mathcal{L}\{y(t)\}=\int_{0}^\infty e^{-st}y(t)dt=\int_{0}^\infty e^{-st}(\int_{0}^t f(t)dt)dt$.

From,here i got confused in dealing with variables.Please provide some suggestion for completing this problem.

Comment: Hint: Change the order of integration. Also, I would choose a different variable of integration, to be "kosher," i.e., maybe have $$\int_{[0, \infty) \times [0, t]} e^{-st} f(u) \ du \ dt $$

Comment: Hint: use integration by parts. And do change the dummy variable in the inner integral.

Comment: @SeanRoberson:I've done the problem by making use of the identity $\mathcal{L}(y'(t))=sY(s)-y(0)$,Where $Y$ is the laplace transform of $y$.

Comment: But how do you prove that identity?

Comment: @Nick:I haven't proved the identity,it is given in text book.OK,how should i approach towards the proof the identity?

Comment: Look at my hint :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $y(t)=\int_0^t f(x)\,dx$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}\left(y \right)(s)&=\int_0^\infty \int_0^t f(x)\,dx\,e^{-st}\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty f(x) \int_x^\infty e^{-st}\,dt\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1s \int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-sx}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1s\mathscr{L}\left(f\right)(s)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!